Convergence of sequences formed by orthocenters, incenters, and centroids in repeated triangle constructions
Now asked on MO here.

Given a scalene triangle $A_1B_1C_1$ , construct a triangle $A_{n+1}B_{n+1}C_{n+1}$ from the triangle $A_nB_nC_n$ where $A_{n+1}$ is the orthocenter of $A_nB_nC_n$, $B_{n+1}$ is the incenter of $A_nB_nC_n$ and $C_{n+1}$ is the centroid of $A_nB_nC_n$, My question is  If this process is repeated indefinitely would the sequences $\{A_n\}$, $\{B_n\}$, $\{C_n\} $ converge ?
There are only four possible scenarios:

The points will converge to a point.
The points will eventually stuck on a loop.
The points will completely diverge.
The points will eventually make an isosceles triangle (or equilateral triangle) which will end the sequence.

All of these scenarios would depend on the initial triangle. So given $\angle A_1$, $\angle B_1$, $\angle C_1, $ how to determine which of the four scenario would happen to the sequences $\{A_n\}$, $\{B_n\}$, $\{C_n\} $?
I tried to draw the first few triangles and see if the point will converge or not.






Graphing the first  25 triangles suggests that the sequence converge.

Here is the graphing the first 30 triangle, If anyone needs them.
If this is true that the three sequences will converge to a point this point will be unique to the triangle, I wonder what extra properties this point have.

It seems that the limit point (assuming it exists) in not in the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers, the distance between  $A_{25} $ and $\overline {B_1C_1}$ (in the triangle 6-9-13) is $0.5360763749467$, the distance between  $B_{25} $ and $\overline {B_1C_1}$ is $0.5360798890437$ and  the distance between  $C_{25} $ and $\overline {B_1C_1}$ is $0.5360789119326$ so the distance between limit point and $\overline {B_1C_1}$ is around $0.53607$

Maybe it depends on the type of triangle. For a equilateral triangle, our experiment ends the moment we start, because they're all the same point in it

Maybe looking at successive Euler lines (joining orthocenter and centroid) and their possible stbilization ?

This category of triangle "GHI" is considered, among others here.
